# Canopy installation error in ubuntu

Tags: canopy

While trying to install canopy I got following error

```
ubuntu@hari-desktop:~/Downloads$ sh canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh
canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh: 32: canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh: 0: not found
canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh: 46: canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh: 0: not found
canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh: 154: canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: run using bash: bash canopy-2.1.3.rh6-x86_64-cp27.sh

Comment: Correct. See user installation instructions at http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/2.1/quick-start/install_linux.html